# Navigate DiGraph in Python-Networkx in both directions

Tags: python, find, networkx, parent

I am rather new both to stackoverflow and Networkx, so don’t get upset, if my questions are not very clever :)

I have a DiGraph where the nodes model different stations in different production pathways in a fab. Every edge connects a “parent” with one “child”. There are few thousands of nodes in a graph.
The production goes parent -> child(ren) -> child(ren) of the child(ren) -> etc
Every child can have 1 or few parents, every parent can have 0, 1 or several children. There might be 1 or few nodes with no parents.

What is the simplest way to navigate:

1. Node -> Parent -> Parent(s) of the Parent -> etc, until reaching the “Parent of all Parents” in the graph
2. Node -> Child(ren) -> Child(ren) of the Child(ren) until reaching all of the Children from this Parent

Putting the results in a excel-like table would be great

Many thanks in advance

LATE EDIT:
Hi abc,
Thanks a lot, you brought me very close to what I need.
BUT I still have a question.

```
    G = nx.DiGraph()
    G.add_edges_from([(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (2, 7), (3, 8), (3, 9), (4, 10)])
    length = nx.single_source_shortest_path_length(G, 1)
    print(length)
```

gives me: {1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 2, 8: 2, 9: 2, 10: 2}
How do I know from this result, if for example 8 is a child of 2, 3 or 4?

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your graph contains an arc (u, v) if u is a parent of v. Then you could use [single_source_shortest_path_length](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.unweighted.single_source_shortest_path_length.html?highlight=single_source_shortest_path_length#networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.unweighted.single_source_shortest_path_length) on G to discover all the children of a given node, and the same function on G reversed (i.e., with all the arcs reversed) to find all the parents of the node.

Example:

```
>>> G = nx.path_graph(n=6, create_using=nx.DiGraph)
>>> G_reversed = G.reverse()
>>> nx.single_source_shortest_path_length(G, 2)
{2: 0, 3: 1, 4: 2, 5: 3}
>>> nx.single_source_shortest_path_length(G_reversed, 2)
{2: 0, 1: 1, 0: 2}
```